# how to modify list of list by removing lists containing elements starting with the same pattern

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list that I would like to modify by removing the list element completely in the case that it contains two elements starting with the same pattern [in that case the same 3 characters].

For example if this is my list of lists:

```
list_of_lists = [['aComp6', 'mot12'], ['aComp6', 'mot24'], ['mot12', 'mot24'],
                 ['mot24', 'fd_dvars'], ['mot24', 'fd_dvars_td'], 
                 ['fd_dvars', 'fd_dvars_td']]
```

I would like to remove these two lists from it:['**mot**12', '**mot**24'] ['**fd_**dvars', '**fd_d**vars_td'] and end up with this:

```
new_list_of_lists = [['aComp6', 'mot12'], ['aComp6', 'mot24'],
                     ['mot24', 'fd_dvars'], ['mot24', 'fd_dvars_td']]
```

In the extended case the inner lists can contain more elements but in any case first three strings are enough.

I am having difficulties coming up a way to compare the elements in each list with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a list comprehension. Assuming the pattern is always 3 characters, and you want to compare every element in each of the inner lists to every other element you can use the following

```
 new_lists_of_lists = [sublist for sublist in list_of_lists if not any(i[:3]==j[:3] and i!=j for i in sublist for j in sublist)]
```

if the pattern isn't always three characters then change the 3 to whatever the pattern is

Comment: in that case 3 is enough to to find the lists to remove. That is what I was trying to come up with and it does what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works:

```
new_list_of_lists = [inner_list for inner_list in list_of_lists \
                     if len(set([x[:3] for x in inner_list])) == len(inner_list)]
```

In other words, select inner lists where the number of distinct 3-character prefixes is equal to the number of elements - in other words, where there are no repeated prefixes.

Comment: I like this method, but I think the check needs to be that the distinct 3-character prefixes is not less than the number of elements in the list (i.e. != len(inner_list)), not comparing it to 1. I think removing lists with any duplicate prefixes is the question, not any where all elements share the same prefix

Comment: yes, one information I added making an edit is that in my real list of lists there is some inner lists with more elements. If they have these matching strings I need the whole list to be removed. In your version it only removes the lists if they only contains these two elements.

Comment: @CHaworth oh, you're right, edited - although it should be `==`, not `!=`, since we're selecting lists in, not filtering them out. @Ilkay it should work now, and here's proof: https://repl.it/repls/DifferentEnergeticConsulting :)

Comment: Although the selected answer is fine too.